# Connecting GND and main ground safety risk

Tags: ground

I am working on power amp and preamp circuit. I have a huge problem with hum and noise. I find out that if I touch any wire with my hand the hum reduced. Then I connect GND and main ground together and the noise and hum almost disappeared.

The power amp and preamp are separated from main voltage with toroidal transformer.

It is allowed to connect GND and ground together and whether there is any danger with that?

[image]

Comment: Try a 100nF, 1000V capacitor.  Then AC is coupled to ground, but not DC.

Comment: There's not enough info. Please post schematics how the devices are now and how you intend to connect "GND" and "main ground" together in the schematics.

Comment: all your audio stack should (almost always) have a common ground. I run a wire between chassis screws to kill the hum if there's no terminal available, like an antenna.

Comment: Do you use an isolated power supply?

Comment: Schematic please

Comment: @rdtsc GND can not be connected directly to main ground ?

Comment: No.  Ground for the device should not connect to the "neutral" wire from your mains power supply at the device.  

Eventually, back at the breaker box, ground is connected to the neutral cable's bus bar but, for safety sake, do not connect them in the device.

Comment: @Justme I added block diagram

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I added block diagram

Comment: @SimSon I added block diagram

Comment: @GTElectronics Could elaborate on what you see as the safety issue?

Comment: @GTElectronics the OP isn't talking about neutral, but protective earth. I see no security risk in doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiring according to your schematic should be safe. The input to your power supply is isolated by a transformer. Thus, regardless of your power supply's internal construction, it's GND line can be safely connected to the mains GND line.

Comment: If I use same design as in the block diagram, do I pass CE standard if GND and main ground are connected together ?

Comment: I do not live in Europe, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CE_marking#Rules_underlying_CE_marking) "The manufacturer of a product affixes the CE marking to it but has to take certain obligatory steps before the product can bear CE marking. The manufacturer must carry out a conformity assessment, set up a technical file, and sign a Declaration stipulated by the leading legislation for the product. The documentation has to be made available to authorities on request." So, there are obligatory steps you must take, which I am not competent to advise you on.

Comment: @mrkefca There are non-isolated power supplies (continuity between PE and GND), that's not a problem for CE marking per se.